# iText7 html to pdf cannot break long words

Tags: word-wrap, itext7, html2pdf

I am using iText7 to convert html to pdf.  I have issue with breaking long words. (Only breaking up words if they don't fit).

```
<td>The labrado is jumping over the fence tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</td>
```

[image]

I have tried to override IsSplitCharacter to always return true, but that causes it to break words at unwanted places like image below (breaking the word "jump-ing").

```
public class CustomSplitCharacters : DefaultSplitCharacters
{
    public override bool IsSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

I apology if this question is similar to other posts.  But i can't seem to find the right solution.  And i don't have enough reputations to follow up on those posts with comments.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a temporary solution

```
public class CustomSplitCharacters : DefaultSplitCharacters
{
    public override bool IsSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos)
    {
        bool baseResult = base.IsSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
        bool myResult = IsSpecialCharacter((char)text.Get(glyphPos).GetUnicode());

        return baseResult || myResult;
    }

    private bool IsSpecialCharacter(char c)
    {
        Regex regexItem = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]");

        return !regexItem.IsMatch(c.ToString());
    }
}
```

This would work for the most cases.  But it still cannot break a long word.  I am still hoping to get an answer for the extreme case.  Your reply is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. For long word does not wrap even when column width is specified. How did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Sadly i still have the problem.